# Concatenate array value with PHP variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have a [key] => [value] array that return a string when calling a function

my problem is when i concatenate a php variable with array value it gives me this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE) in C:/...

My Code:

```
function language( $phrase , $name ) {
     static $language= array (
                              'hello' => 'Hello '.$name,
                              'welcome' => 'Welcome '.$name,
                              'goodbye' => 'Goodbye'.$name,
     )
       return $language[$phrase];
}
```

my expected output when calling

```
echo language("hello", "name");
```

output: Hello name

is there any other way to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot initialize static variables with parameters, they must be constants.  If you corrected the syntax of your original code (missing `;`) you would have get the error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations in

You could achieve it though by setting static to some dummy value (i.e. `null`) and then using an `if` to set the value when it isn't already set...

```
function language( $phrase , $name ) {
    static $language= null;

    if ( $language == null )    {
        $language = array (
            'hello' => 'Hello '.$name,
            'welcome' => 'Welcome '.$name,
            'goodbye' => 'Goodbye'.$name,
            );
    }
    return $language[$phrase];
}
```

Comment: Even `static $language;` is enough.

Comment: @u_mulder thanks, but I tend to be a bit pedantic and prefer to set any variable I create.