# String array count and merge to one

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have searched around the web, but dont know the right keywords to find the solution.

Example code:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

$json_components = array();
$count = 0;

foreach ($arr as &$value) { $count++;
  $array_string = array("type" => "list", 'name' => 'example '.$count.'');
}

$json_components = array_merge($json_components, $array_string);

print_r($json_components);
die();
```

In the foreach there's a **$array_string** this can have the same names/keys/values each time (with small differences). 
What I want to succeed is to merge it to one array.

I have tried: $array_string.count = array("type" => "list", 'name' => 'example '.$count.''); but this is not working.

Final result what I'm looking for:

```
$json_components = array(
 array("type" => "list", 'name' => 'example 1'),
 array("type" => "list", 'name' => 'example 2'),
 array("type" => "list", 'name' => 'example 3'),
 array("type" => "list", 'name' => 'example 4')
);

print_r($json_components);
die();
```

Comment: Related: [Concatenate array value with PHP variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53574006/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

Simply add to the array like this and then you dont need to merge the arrays

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

$json_components = array();

foreach ($arr as $value) { 
    $json_components[] = [ "type" => "list", 
                           'name' => "example $value"
                      ];
}

print_r($json_components);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => list
            [name] => example 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => list
            [name] => example 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => list
            [name] => example 3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => list
            [name] => example 4
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use loop with `array_merge()`, you can just use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)  function:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

$json_components = array();

$new_array = array_map(function($val) {
    return array("type" => "list", 'name' => 'example '. $val);
}, $arr);

print_r($new_array);
die();
```

Here is a working snippet: https://3v4l.org/BvaVF